# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have develop a menu in WordPress site using Advanced Custom Fields.It works fine for it's home page not for other..As a example when website directs to it's search page, menu disappears.Need it to appears on every page of the site.

Menu code is as below

```
             <div id="main-menu" class="menu-list">

                <?php if( have_rows('header_links') ): ?>

                  <ul class="list-inline m-menu-ul">

                  <?php while( have_rows('header_links') ): the_row(); 

                    // vars
                    $menu_title = get_sub_field('menu_title');
                    $menu_link = get_sub_field('menu_link');

                    ?>

                    <li class="">

                      <?php if( $menu_link ): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $menu_link; ?>">
                      <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php echo $menu_title; ?>

                      <?php if( $menu_link ): ?>
                        </a>
                      <?php endif; ?>

                    </li>

                  <?php endwhile; ?>

                  </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>

              </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have defined custom field "header_links" for the home page only. if you want to display the menu in all the pages then either you can pass the home page id as a second argument in the have_rows like this:

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );
$home_id = $page->ID;
if(have_rows('header_links',$home_id)):
while( have_rows('header_links',$home_id) ): the_row($home_id);
```

Comment: Hi Darsh khakhkhar,  Still not working ;(  Do you have any solutions for me?

Comment: In which page it exactly working ? what is page title? And you need to paste the $home_id in if statement as well